# Why my udev rule not working

Tags: touchpad, udev

I checked forum and google but I dont found the answer. I try to add udev rule to disable touchpad when mouse is connected. First i wrote general rule to check it working, but dont. This is the rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/touchpadtoggle.sh"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="input", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/touchpadtoggle.sh"
```

this rule is placed in /etc/udev/rules.d/00-touchpad.rules

and this is test bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send "Test"
```

Bash script work good. If I type "/usr/local/bin/touchpadtoggle.sh" in command line, notification is showed.

Comment: Welcome to AU ! You need to clarify what yr bash script (as shown) has to do with yr udev rule ?

Comment: Update initramfs  and reboot `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is udev runs as root and so runs your script as root, not as you.  You'll want this for your real script, but this is why `notify-send` isn't sending *you* the notification when run by udev.  Also the `DISPLAY` environment variable will need to be manually set, as udev runs in a minimal environment.

Change your script to the following, replacing `$USER` with your username:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u $USER DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "Test"
```

Also to ensure the new rules were (re)read before, run:

```
sudo udevadm control -R
```

Comment: Hi Martin, indeed there exists the suspicion that `DISPLAY` is not defined correctly. But I don't know that `udev` runs as root. It runs in its own restricted `udev` environment.  Also yr solution forces user to input `sudo`'s password ***every time*** the rules trigger. That goes completely against the automated process triggering that `udev` permits. --- instead, for one-screen displays, just writing `DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/notify-send "test"` after the shebang in the script should be enough.

Comment: @Cbhihe You're wrong.  Try testing it yourself.  `sudo` is needed and won't ask for any passwords from root or the same user. `sudo -u <YOUR USER NAME> DISPLAY=:0 notify-send $(whoami)` when run via udev displays "root".

Answer (score 0):

Your `udev` rules may either (i) fall short of identifying your mouse as a usb device, or (ii) include some sort of on-display (stdout) notification that is not understood by the minimal udev environment in which your rules operate. (One example of that is by default they don't know your display exist.)

To dispel the latter doubt, please show the content of `/usr/local/bin/touchpadtoggle.sh`).

For the former, open terminal and with its windows focused, unplug your mouse and do the following in terminal:

```
 $ lsusb
 $ udevadm monitor --property
```

Then plug in your mouse and ***immediately afterward*** quit the cmd in terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Do so rapidly, without touching the mouse itself. It is not harmful but messy and you will get a lot of output on your screen if you don't do things correctly . 
You will recognize the following outputs (here for my own mouse):

```
 $ lsusb
 Bus 002 Device 004: ID 192f:0916 Avago Technologies, Pte.
```

My mouse is on Bus 002. What follows is the vendor's ID, 192f, and the model ID, 0916. When available and known, product and vendor IDs are two attributes that can be used to identify a particular device unambiguously in a `udev` rule. I'd favor them over the overly simple test `SUBSYSTEM=="input"` which I find does not discriminate between devices. Confirm and refine that with the output of the second cmd:

```
$ udevadm monitor --property
[.......]
UDEV  [25696.403834] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.4/2-3.4:1.0/0003:192F:0916.0003/input/input22/event4 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-192f_USB_Optical_Mouse-event-mouse /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:3.4:1.0-event-mouse
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event4
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.4/2-3.4:1.0/0003:192F:0916.0003/input/input22/event4
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_MODEL=USB_Optical_Mouse
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Optical\x20Mouse
ID_MODEL_ID=0916
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:3.4:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_7-usb-0_3_4_1_0
ID_REVISION=0200
ID_SERIAL=192f_USB_Optical_Mouse
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=192f
ID_VENDOR_ENC=192f
ID_VENDOR_ID=192f
MAJOR=13
MINOR=68
SEQNUM=2567
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=5875811

UDEV  [25696.407470] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.4/2-3.4:1.0/0003:192F:0916.0003/input/input22/mouse0 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-192f_USB_Optical_Mouse-mouse /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:3.4:1.0-mouse
DEVNAME=/dev/input/mouse0
       *^^^ that's my device name ! ^^^*
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.4/2-3.4:1.0/0003:192F:0916.0003/input/input22/mouse0  
*^^^ that's my device path ! ^^^*
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1
ID_MODEL=USB_Optical_Mouse
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Optical\x20Mouse
ID_MODEL_ID=0916
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:3.4:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_7-usb-0_3_4_1_0
ID_REVISION=0200
ID_SERIAL=192f_USB_Optical_Mouse
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=192f
ID_VENDOR_ENC=192f
ID_VENDOR_ID=192f
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
MAJOR=13
MINOR=32
SEQNUM=2566
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=5875565
```

*[I stopped monitoring here with CTRL-C]*

With the above you know that the kernel recognizes my input device as either `/dev/input/event4` or `/dev/input/mouse0`. Note that you find again for confirmation:  `ID_MODEL_ID=0916` and `ID_VENDOR_ID=192f`. With that, I can write a `udev` rule that should recognize that specific device. Just adding `ID_MODEL_ID=="0916",ID_VENDOR_ID=="192f"` to `SUBSYSTEM=="input"` in the `udev` rules above should be enough of a cure.

There is another way of doing it, which I favor. Since I know my device name (from above), in terminal I do:

```
$ udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/mouse0)
                                                         ^^^^^^^
                                                   may be different for you
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.4/2-3.4:1.0/0003:192F:0916.0003/input/input22/mouse0':
    KERNEL=="mouse0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.4/2-3.4:1.0/0003:192F:0916.0003/input/input22':
    KERNELS=="input22"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{name}=="USB Optical Mouse"
    ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:1d.7-3.4/input0"
    ATTRS{uniq}==""
    ATTRS{properties}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.4/2-3.4:1.0/0003:192F:0916.0003':
    KERNELS=="0003:192F:0916.0003"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
    DRIVERS=="hid-generic"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.4/2-3.4:1.0':
    KERNELS=="2-3.4:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usbhid"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.4':
    KERNELS=="2-3.4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="3.4"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="192f"
    ATTRS{speed}=="1.5"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="8"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="98mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0200"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="62095"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0916"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB Optical Mouse"
```

So, provided I don't want to display anything on screen, the `udev` rule becomes:

```
ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="192f",ATTRS{idProduct}=="0916",RUN+="/usr/local/bin/touchpadtoggle.sh"
```

*Change values "192f" and "0916" to suit your hw.*
 
HTH. Feedback welcome.